# Is Lambda Expression just capture objects before it?

Tags: c++, lambda

I was assuming that lambda expression in C++ is just an anonymous function. Thus every time I call it will just like calling other ordinary functions.

Then I came up with this code :

```
int x = 0,y = 0;
auto qqq = [x, &y] {
    std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y: " << y << std::endl;
    ++y;
};

x = y = 77;
qqq();
qqq();
std::cout << "final y:" << y << std::endl;
```

The `x` is captured by value and `y` is captured by reference.
I thought that I have changed the value of `x` and `y` to 77. So If I call qqq(), it will print `x: 77`. However, it prints `x: 0`.

Then I changed the location of lambda expression:

```
  int x = 0,y = 0;
+ x = y = 77;
  auto qqq = [x, &y] {//...};
-
  qqq();
```

It yield x:77 as expected. So this just wired, why lambda expression is designed like this? Does this means that if I want to reuse the lambda expression later, I have to write it again?